# sed command failure in hashicorp packer shell provisioner

Tags: shell, sed, packer

Using sed command's in-place update, I'm trying to search a string in a file, and replace it with multiple lines. This is how I would like to update the file.

Before sed: foo.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
```

sed command:

```
sed -i 's|#!\/bin\/sh|#!\\/bin\\/sh\n\n. \\/etc\\/company\\/aws_functions\n\nif [ -f \\/etc\\/company\\/user_data ];then\n\t. \\/etc\\/company\\/user_data\nfi\n|g' /tmp/foo.sh
```

After sed: foo.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/company/aws_functions

if [ -f /etc/company/user_data ];then
    . /etc/company/user_data
fi
```

This works perfectly, however when trying to execute the same command using packer shell provisioner, I keep getting following error.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated `s' command[0m
```

I followed https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/9091 as well, but no luck. Any pointers to fix this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: search here and on the internet for info about `sed`s `a` (append) or `r` (read) options. Good luck.\

Comment: How does your provisioner section in your packer template look?